# Sorting an multidimension array using usort fails

Tags: php, arrays, fatal-error, execution-time, usort

I tried to use custom-made usort funciton. when I loaded 5 cell array this runned over 30 seconds and then threw a fatal error.

I tried to find if I've been made an infinite loop but didn't founded it.

array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => iPhone 5s 32 GB [Price] => 0 [Description] => A new Apple Product [Image_URL] => [Business_ID] => 6 [Keywords] => ["iPhone","iPhone 5s","Apple","32 GB"] ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => iPhone 4s 32 G [Price] => 300 [Description] => Apple iPhone 4S [Image_URL] => [Business_ID] => 6 [Keywords] => ["iPhone 4S","iPhone","Apple","32 GB"] ) )
```

search:

```
$searchTerm = "iphone 5s";
```

code:

```
if (!empty($searchTerm)) {
    $searchTermWords = explode(" ", $searchTerm);
    usort($products, function($a, $b) use ($searchTermWords) {

        $aArr = explode(" ", $a['Name']);
        $bArr = explode(" ", $b['Name']);

        $aKeywords = $a['Keywords'];
        $bKeywords = $b['Keywords'];
        //todo: explode description too.

        $aCount = 0;
        $bCount = 0;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $searchTermWords; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $aKeywords; $j++) {
                if (strpos($aKeywords[$j], $searchTermWords[$i]) !== false)
                    $aCount++;
            }
            for ($j = 0; $j < $aArr; $j++) {
                if ($aArr[$j] == $searchTermWords[$i])
                    $aCount++;
            }
            for ($j = 0; $j < $bKeywords; $j++) {
                if (strpos($bKeywords[$j], $searchTermWords[$i]) !== false)
                    $bCount++;
            }
            for ($j = 0; $j < $bArr; $j++) {
                if ($bArr[$j] == $searchTermWords[$i])
                    $bCount++;
            }
        }

        return $bCount - $aCount;
    });
}
```

Error (after 30 seconds):

```
 Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/itay/public_html/tester.php(30) : eval()'d code on line 94
```

if it's imprtant for some reason everything is made from eval() function.

Comment: What should the result be after sorting the array?

Comment: Actually, is this specific case exactly like it was given.

Answer (score 0):

You get the Fatal Error because your script doesn't exit properly. There is a For loop that runs infinitly.

Your `for()` loops are checked against the elements itself and not the number of elements. Are you trying to loop for the number of element in the array ? If so, try to use the `count($array)`  to return the number of elements in the array. Then use that count to loop using the foreach.